# Create a DB2 Calendar table for 20 years with columns dependant on the original date

Tags: sql, database, date, db2, recursive-query

I'm trying to create a calendar table for 20 years ranging from 2000 - 2020. The aim is to have one row per day along with some other columns that will use logic based on the calendar date generated. An example of this would be having One column as the calendar date (2000-01-01) and the year column reading the year from the values within the calendar date column (2000).

The code for the table is below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.CALENDAR(
CALENDAR_DATE         DATE    NOT NULL,
CALENDAR_YEAR         INTEGER NOT NULL,
CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME   VARCHAR(100),
CALENDAR_DAY_OF_MONTH INTEGER NOT NULL,
CALENDAR_DAY_OF_WEEK  INTEGER NOT NULL,
CALENDAR_DAY_NAME     VARCHAR(100),
CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH   INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

At the moment, I have a bunch of insert statements that manually insert rows for this table over 20 years. I'm looking to make an insert statement with variables instead and this insert statement would insert data in daily increments until the start date variable is not less than the end date variable.

Currently, I cannot get this to work at all let alone include any logic for any other columns.

Code for the variable insert statement:

```
declare startdate DATE, enddate DATEset startdate = '2000-01-01'
set enddate = DATEADD(yy,20,startdate)
while startdate < enddate
begin insert into TEST.CALENDAR (CALENDAR_DATE) select startdate
set startdate = DATEADD(dd,1,startdate) end
```

Would anyone have any ideas of how I can get this to work?

Comment: Side note: your name columns are far larger than required.  Also, you should probably add essentially every piece of data imaginable - `DAY_OF_WEEK_ISO` (where `Monday = 1`) is near the top of the list, day-of-year is good, the next day/month/year can really simplify range queries (instead of needing date math, you potentially have index range access).  Don't have end-of-month (use "less than next month" instead).  If you have fiscal year/period/day-of-period, include them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a DB2 recursive query and date functions:

Consider:

```
with cte (
    calendar_date,
    calendar_year,
    calendar_month_number,
    calendar_month_name,
    calendar_day_of_month,
    calendar_day_of_week,
    calendar_day_name
) as (
    select 
        calendar_date,
        year(calendar_date),
        month(calendar_date),
        monthname(calendar_date),
        dayofmonth(calendar_date),
        dayofweek(calendar_date),
        dayname(calendar_date)
    from (values(date('2000-01-01'))) as t(calendar_date)
    union all
    select 
        calendar_date + 1,
        year(calendar_date + 1),
        month(calendar_date + 1),
        monthname(calendar_date + 1),
        dayofmonth(calendar_date + 1),
        dayofweek(calendar_date + 1),
        dayname(calendar_date + 1)
    from cte where calendar_date < date('2021-01-01')
)
select * from cte
```

Note: it is unclear to me what column `CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH` means, so I left it apart.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b03ad429105eb2607773c99705c814f6)** for the first 10 days:

```
CALENDAR_DATE | CALENDAR_YEAR | CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER | CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME | CALENDAR_DAY_OF_MONTH | CALENDAR_DAY_OF_WEEK | CALENDAR_DAY_NAME
------------: | ------------: | --------------------: | ------------------: | --------------------: | -------------------: | ----------------:
   2000-01-01 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     1 |                    7 |          Saturday
   2000-01-02 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     2 |                    1 |            Sunday
   2000-01-03 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     3 |                    2 |            Monday
   2000-01-04 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     4 |                    3 |           Tuesday
   2000-01-05 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     5 |                    4 |         Wednesday
   2000-01-06 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     6 |                    5 |          Thursday
   2000-01-07 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     7 |                    6 |            Friday
   2000-01-08 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     8 |                    7 |          Saturday
   2000-01-09 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                     9 |                    1 |            Sunday
   2000-01-10 |          2000 |                     1 |             January |                    10 |                    2 |            Monday
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem • Relational Knowledge

> Currently, I cannot get this to work at all let alone include any logic for any other columns.

Well, there is a reason for that:

- Since the **Relational Model** is founded on **First Order Predicate Calculus** (aka First Order Logic)

  - there is nothing in the universe that cannot be defined in terms of the *RM*, and stored in a Relational database (ie. one that complies with the *RM*), such that it can be retrieved easily and without limitation (including complex queries and DW).
- Since **SQL** is the data sub-language for the *RM*, and it is **Set-oriented**

  - there is nothing, no code requirement, that cannot be implemented in Set-oriented SQL.
- DB2 is a Relational database engine, with genuine Set-oriented processing, using SQL.

It appears that you are not aware of that.  Instead, you are attempting to:

1. define low-level data structures

   - that you think you need for your programming,
   - rather than ones that are required within the *RM* and SQL,
     that define the data, as data, and nothing but data.
2. write code that you need to manipulate those data structures, which is:

   - (a) procedural (one row at a time; `WHILE` loops; `CURSORS`; similar abominations), instead of Set-oriented, and
   - (b) thus the code is consequently complex, if not impossible.
   - Not to mention, slow as maple syrup in winter
   - Rather than using the available blindingly fast, Set-oriented code, which will be simple and straight-forward.
   - The problem may be a bit tricky, but the tables and the code required are not.

### Problem • Platform Knowledge

> An example of this would be having One column as the calendar date (2000-01-01) and the year column reading the year from the values within the calendar date column (2000)

That breaks two principles, and results in massive duplication *within each row*:

1. Use the correct datatype for the datum, as you have with `CALENDAR_DATE`. **Only**.
   It is a `DATE` datatype
   Using the built-in `DATE` datatype and `DATE_PART(), DATEADD()` functions means that DB2 controls the year; month; day; etc values
   and all `DATE` errors such as `29-Feb-2019` and `31-Sep-2019` are prevented
   as opposed to your code, which may have one or more errors.

   - a column that contains **any** part of a date must be stored as a `DATE` datatype (any part of a time as `TIME`; date and time as `DATETIME`; etc).
2. It breaks Codd's First Normal Form (as distinct from the ever-changing insanity purveyed as "1NF" by the pretenders)
   .
   **Each domain** [column, datum] **must be Atomic wrt the platform**
   .
   DB2 handles `DATE` and `DATE_PART()` perfectly, so there is no excuse.
3. **All** the following columns are redundant, duplicates of `CALENDAR_DATE` *in the same row`:

   ```
   CALENDAR_YEAR
   CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER
   CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME
   CALENDAR_DAY_OF_MONTH
   CALENDAR_DAY_OF_WEEK
   CALENDAR_DAY_NAME
   CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH
   ```

   - Kind of like buying a car (`CALENDAR_DATE`), putting it drive, and then walking beside it (7 duplicated DATE parts).  You need to understand the platform; SQL, and trust it a little.
   - Not only that, but you will have a lot of fun and no hair left, trying to populate those duplicate columns out without making mistakes.
   - It needs to be said, you need to know all the date Functions in DB2 reasonably well, in order to use it proficiently.
   - They are duplicate columns because the values can be **derived** easily via `DATE_PART()`, something like:

   ```
   SELECT  DATE,
       Year       = DATE_PART( 'YEAR', DATE ),
       MonthNo    = DATE_PART( 'MONTH', DATE ),
       MonthName  = SUBSTR( ‘January  February March    April    May      June     July     August   SeptemberOctober  November December ‘, 
                    ( DATE_PART( 'MONTH', DATE ) - 1 ) * 9 + 1, 9 ),
       DayOfMonth = DATE_PART( 'DAY', DATE ),
       DayOfWeek  = DATE_PART( 'DOW', DATE ),
       DayName    = SUBSTR( ‘Sunday   Monday   Tuesday  WednesdayThursday Friday   Saturday',
                    ( DATE_PART( 'DOW', DATE ) - 1 ) * 9 + 1, 9 ),
       YearMonth  = DATE_PART( 'YEAR', DATE ) * 100 + DATE_PART( 'MONTH', DATE )
   FROM TEST.CALENDAR
   ```

   - In Sybase, I do not have to use `SUBSTR()` because I have the MonthName and DayName values in tables, the query is simpler still.  Or else use `CASE`.
4. Do not prefix the columns in each table with the table name.  In SQL, to reference a column in a particular table, in order to resolve ambiguity, use:
   .
   `TableName.ColumnName`
   .
   Same as prefixing the table name with an user name `TEST.CALENDAR`.

   - The full specification is as follows, with DB2 supplying the relevant defaults based on the context of the command:
     .
     `[SERVER.][Database.][Owner.][Table.]Column`
   - The reason for this rule is this.  Columns in one table may well be related to the same column in another table, and should be named the same.  That is the nature of *Relational*.  If you break this rule, it will retard your progressive understanding of the *Relational Model*, and of SQL, its data sub-language.

### Problem • Data Knowledge

> The aim is to have one row per day along with some other columns that will use logic based on the calendar date generated.

Why on earth would you do that ?

We store Facts about the universe in a Relational database.  **Only**.

- We do not need to store non-facts, such as:

  - `Kyle's name is`**`NOT`**`"Fred"`
  - `CustomerCode "IBX" does`**`NOT`**`exist`.
- A non-fact is simply the *absence* of a stored Fact.
- If `Fred` does not exist in the `Person` table, and you
  `SELECT ... FROM Person WHERE Name = "Fred"`
  you will obtain an empty result set.
  As it should be.

You are storing the grid ***that you imagine***, consisting of
20 years
* 365 days
* whatever Key is relevant [eg. `CustomerCode`, etc),
in the form of rows.

- That will only keep the database chock-full of empty rows, storing non-facts such as [eg.] `CustomerCode XYZ` has no event on each date for the next 20 years.
- What you imagine, is the result set, or the view, which you may construct in the GUI app.  It is not the storage.
- Store only Facts, [eg.] actual Events per Customer.

### Solution

Now for the solution.

> <sub>Let me assure you that I have implemented this structure, upon which fairly complex logic has been built, in quite a few databases.
>
>   - The problem is, educating the developers in order to get them to write correct SQL code.
>
>   - Your situation is that of a developer, trying to not only write non-simple code, but to define the structures upon which it depends.
>
>   - Two distinct and different sciences.</sub>

### Data Model

First, a visual data model, in order to understand the data properly.

[image: KyleTA]

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners.

#### SQL DDL

Only because you appear to work at that level:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.Customer (
    CustomerCode  CHAR(6)  NOT NULL,
    Name          CHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK
        PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerCode )
    CONSTRAINT AK1
        UNIQUE ( Name )
    ...
    );

CREATE TABLE TEST.Event (
    CustomerCode  CHAR(6)  NOT NULL,
    Date          DATE     NOT NULL,
    Event         CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk
        PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerCode, Date )
    CONSTRAINT Customer_Schedules_Event
        FOREIGN KEY         ( CustomerCode )
        REFERENCES Customer ( CustomerCode )
    ...
    );
```

1. `INSERT` a row only when a `Customer` reserves a `Date`
   Non-facts are not stored.
2. `SELECT ... WHERE CustomerCode = ... AND Date = ...`
   will obtain a row if the Customer has booked an Event on that Date
   will obtain nothing (empty result set) if the Customer has **NOT** booked an Event on that Date
3. If you need to store **recurring** Events, such as a birthday for the next 20 years, use a Projection in SQL to generate the 20 INSERT commands, which is the Set-oriented method.

   - If you cannot code a Projection, and only then, write a `WHILE` loop, which is procedural, one row per execution.

Please feel free to ask questions, the more specific the better.

---

<sub>As you can see, this Question is really about **How to set up a Calendar for Events**, but I won't change the title until I am sure this answer is what you are seeking.  And about modelling data for a Relational database.  I will add the tag.</sub>

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP about events, not sure where that came from.  While you answer is a decent primer on RDBMS, you seem to be unaware that a calendar table with "redundant, duplicates of `CALENDAR_DATE`"  is a very useful real world implementation in any DB.

Comment: To echo @Charles - a calendar table is probably the **most useful** analysis-supporting table you can have.  If you include the right set of columns, you can turn queries that normally require function calls to simple joins on indexed columns (for example, `GROUP BY MONTH(n)`).  For companies with things like 52/53 week calendars, including fiscal year/period/day-of-period vastly simplifies these sorts of queries.

Comment: @Charles @Clockwork-Muse I have about implemented about 12 Calendars over the decades.  1) No question, a Calendar table containing 20 years of daily rows simplifies queries, but it is totally unnecessary if one can **Project** a Calendar for whatever duration, without a table.  2) I have given the code to extract `CALENDAR_DATE` components.  There is no excuse for redundant duplicate columns in each row.   Use Inline Views, and do your "simple JOINs" from those components.  3) The Calendar has no purpose, in and of itself, unless you have Events of some kind.  As you have alluded.